# COCO json annotation to YOLO txt format

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, coco

[image]

how to convert a single COCO JSON annotation file into a YOLO darknet format?? like below
each individual image has separate filename.txt file
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I built a tool
https://github.com/tw-yshuang/coco2yolo

Download this repo and use the following command:

```sh
python3 coco2yolo.py [OPTIONS]
```

## [coc2yolo](https://github.com/tw-yshuang/coco2yolo)

```sh
Usage: coco2yolo.py [OPTIONS] [CAT_INFOS]...

Options:
  -ann-path, --annotations-path TEXT
                                  JSON file. Path for label.  [required]
  -img-dir, --image-download-dir TEXT
                                  The directory of the image data place.
  -task-dir, --task-categories-dir TEXT
                                  Build a directory that follows the task-required categories.
  -cat-t, --category-type TEXT    Category input type. (interactive | file)  [default: interactive]
  -set, --set-computing-type TEXT
                                  Set Computing for the data. (union | intersection)  [default: union]
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 7):

My classmates and I have created a python package called [PyLabel](https://pypi.org/project/pylabel) to help others with this task and other labelling tasks.

Our package does this conversion! You can see an example in this notebook https://github.com/pylabel-project/samples/blob/main/coco2yolov5.ipynb.

You're answer should be in there! But you should be able to do this conversion by doing something like:

```
!pip install pylabel
from pylabel import importer
dataset = importer.ImportCoco(path=path_to_annotations, path_to_images=path_to_images)
dataset.export.ExportToYoloV5(dataset)
```

You can find the source code that is used behind the scenes here https://github.com/pylabel-project/

Comment: No it's not working, it converting it to YAML, not a txt file !

Comment: @Derek `dataset.export.ExportToYoloV5(dataset)`: shouldn't the argument of `ExportToYoloV5()` method be something line `ExportToYoloV5(output_path='./yolo')` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source tool called [makesense.ai](https://www.makesense.ai/) for annotating your images. You can download YOLO txt format once you annotate your images. But you won't be able to download the annotated images.

Comment: This does not address the question. The question is how to convert an existing JSON formatted dataset to YAML format, not how to export a dataset into YAML format.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me**

**I have loaded all the images in images/all_images directory. I used coco .json annotations differently for train/test/val. You can change accordingly.  Make sure to create directory accordingly.**

```html
import os
import json
import shutil

# load json and save directory for labels train/val/test
coco_file = 'labels/val.json'
save_folder = 'labels/val'



#source of all the images and destination folder for train/test/val
source_path = "images/all_images"
destination_path = "images/val"


# Use os.listdir() to get a list of filenames in the folder
file_names = os.listdir(source_path)

with open(coco_file) as f:
    coco = json.load(f)

images = coco['images']
annotations = coco['annotations'] 
categories = {cat['id']: cat['name'] for cat in coco['categories']}

#os.makedirs(save_folder, exist_ok=True)

for ann in annotations:
    image = next(img for img in images if (img['id'] == ann['image_id']))
    if (image["file_name"] not in file_names):
        continue
    #print(f"image in annotations =   {type(image['id'])}")
    width, height = image['width'], image['height']
    x_center = (ann['bbox'][0] + ann['bbox'][2] / 2) / width
    y_center = (ann['bbox'][1] + ann['bbox'][3] / 2) / height
    bbox_width = ann['bbox'][2] / width
    bbox_height = ann['bbox'][3] / height
    category_id = ann['category_id']
    image_id = ann['image_id']

    filename = image['file_name']
    label_filename = filename.split('.jpg')[0]
    label_path = os.path.join(save_folder, f'{label_filename}.txt')
    with open(label_path, 'a') as f:

        segmentation_points_list = []
        for segmentation in ann['segmentation']:
            # Check if any element in segmentation is a string
            if any(isinstance(point, str) for point in segmentation):
                continue  # Skip this segmentation if it contains strings

            segmentation_points = [str(float(point) / width) for point in segmentation]
            segmentation_points_list.append(' '.join(segmentation_points))
            segmentation_points_string = ' '.join(segmentation_points_list)
            line = '{} {}\n'.format(categories, segmentation_points_string)
            f.write(line)
            segmentation_points_list.clear()
    image_source = source_path + f'/{image["file_name"]}'
    shutil.copy(image_source, destination_path)
```

Answer (score -6):

There is three ways.

1. use roboflow https://roboflow.com/formats (You can find another solution also)
   [image]

You can find some usage guide for roboflow. e.g.
https://medium.com/red-buffer/roboflow-d4e8c4b52515

2. search 'convert coco format to yolo format' -> you will find some open-source codes to convert annotations to yolo format.
3. write your own code to convert coco format to yolo format

Comment: This is one of the methods to convert the file format but the data will be publicised.