# Creating balanced dataset for YOLO v5 with each image having multiple annotations

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

Currently using the YOLO v5 code from this https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 in which each txt has a line referring to the `<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>` (image below). Each image has multiple classes (in the annotation file below the image has a `<object-class>` of `0` and `27`). The goal is to select an equal number of `object-class` from the entire dataset. Currently, the issue is that the image comes with the other labels/bounding boxes too. How can I filter so only a certain row is read from the annotation file? Currently have 1000s of annotation files.

[image: Multiple annotations image]

image source: [COCO json annotation to YOLO txt format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398965/coco-json-annotation-to-yolo-txt-format)

Comment: What's the "why" behind what you're trying to do? You could do this by filtering out examples of the over-represented classes, but in practice I've never seen this lead to improved model performance.

Comment: Hi @BradDwyer! Thanks for your comment! Basically trying to create a balanced dataset to avoid an overly optimistic accuracy since the model will generally pick the class it sees most often.

Comment: Class imbalance isn't a huge problem with modern models. Eg the COCO dataset has 100x more people than fire hydrants & models seem to do Ok.

It's way more valuable to add more examples of your uncommon classes than to cut down on your common classes.

Comment: That is a good point with COCO, Do you think that the model will be more bias towards 'people' class then when testing? Would you recommend any reference that talks about this idea? @BradDwyer

Comment: The mean average precision metric measures this already. If the model has a good mAP then it should be Ok. I don't; just personal experience. The only time I've seen it _really_ be a problem is if the model decides "guess nothing" is the best way to maximize its score and therefore doesn't learn to identify a certain thing. This is usually only if something is _severely_ underrepresented (eg a specific rare manufacturing defect that only happens once in every 1000 images).

Comment: Ohh thank you @BradDwyer!! Is there any reference you can point me to which also mentions this?